# Supersized slideshow, images of different sizes/aspect ratios, center images

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, supersized

I have a gallery with images with different sizes. Some are portrait and some are landscape. With the newest versions of JQuery and Supersized, is it possible to:

a) show all my images proportionally at 100% of the #supersized ul, without my landscape format images being cut off, and all images still resizing proportionally as the window is resized?

b) center those images horizontally, and as they become smaller, horizontally and vertically?

Or is there another plugin out there we can 
Here is my call to Supersized with the Wordpress Loop:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                        $.supersized({

                            // Functionality
                            slideshow               :   1,
                            start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                            new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                            image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
                            transition              :   6,  
                            autoplay                :   1,
                            slide_interval          :   7000,
                            transition_speed        :   1000,                                  
                            // Size & Position                         
                            min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                            min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                            vertical_center         :   0,          // Vertically center background
                            horizontal_center       :   0,          // Horizontally center background
                            fit_always              :   1,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                            fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                            fit_landscape           :   1,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                            // Components
                            thumb_links             :   1,
                            thumbnail_navigation    :   1,
                            slide_links             :   0,
                            keyboard_nav            :   1,
                            slides                  :   [       

                            <?php 
                            $category = get_queried_object();
                            $cid = $category->term_id;
                            $args = array('post_type'=>'photo', 'cat'=>$cid);
                            $i = 0;
                            $posts = query_posts( $args );
                            $count = count($posts) - 1;

                            $q = new WP_Query( $args );

                            if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); 
                                        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                                        $featured_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'square' );

                                        if ($i != $count) {     
                                            echo "{ image : '". $featured_src[0] ."', title :''},";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "{ image : '". $featured_src[0] ."', title :''}";
                                        }
                                        $i++;
                                        endwhile; 
                                         ?>
                            ],
                            progress_bar: 0

                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

And here is my CSS (specific to category images, as I have an actual fullscreen Supersized somewhere else in the page):

```
    body.category #supersized-loader { margin:auto 0; position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:0; width:60px; height:60px; margin:-30px 0 0 -30px; text-indent:-999em; background:url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center;}
body.category #supersized {left:240px;display:block; position:fixed; margin:0 auto; overflow:hidden; z-index:1; height:100%; width:100%; /*max-width:1280px;max-height:720px;*/}
body.category #supersized img {width:auto; height:auto; position:relative; display:none; outline:none; border:none;}
body.category #supersized.speed img { -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor; image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; } /*Speed*/
body.category #supersized.quality img { -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; image-rendering: optimizeQuality; }         /*Quality*/

body.category #supersized li { display:block; list-style:none; z-index:-30; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:#272727; }
body.category #supersized a { width:100%; height:100%; display:block; }
body.category #supersized li.prevslide { z-index:-20; }
body.category #supersized li.activeslide { z-index:-10; }
body.category #supersized li.image-loading { background:#111 url(../img/progress.gif) no-repeat center center; width:100%; height:100%; }
body.category #supersized li.image-loading img{ visibility:hidden; }
body.category #supersized li.prevslide img, body.category #supersized li.activeslide img{ display:inline; }
```